# Sencha touch - youtube video as iframe

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

As i understand that we can't play youtube video with `Ext.Video` component. so I've used `Iframe` to embed the video into my `Ext.container`, when i tested this in google chrome, it worked fine.
but, when i opened the test url in Android phone or Android emulator, its not working properly.
please see the attached Image.

[image: Youtube Embed as iframe not seems working!]

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Try ext-ux-youtubeplayer: http://code.google.com/p/ext-ux-youtubeplayer/.

Comment: Mubix: Thanks for the info.. will check it out.. is there any demo on that Ext UX youtube player?

Comment: still no luck, it's working on pc browser normal, but android emulator or android device its not working.. not sure how to use mubix's solution.. if there are any demos on that please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

i changed the embed url to
http://www.youtube.com/embed/ and it started working, but it's not good.. when i change phone direction, it really behaves different.. but for now it solved my problem